# problem in php when retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one problem regarding retriving data from database. I have created one database in userrecord and its table name is tbl_user. I am trying to display the user information when they log in the system. i.e view logged user profile. The code is as follows:

```
<?php
    include("auth_user.inc.php"); // authrization page
    $uname=$_SESSION['user']; // logged user name
    $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root"," ");
    mysql_select_db("userrecord",$connection);
    $sql=("select * from table_user where uname ='$uname'");
    $result=@mysql_query($sql,$connection);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Account</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#33CCFF">
        <br>Your Details Information Is Shown Below:<br><br>
        First Name:<?php echo $row['fname'];?><br>
        Last Name:<?php echo $row['lname'];?><br>
        Address:<?php echo $row['address'];?><br>
        E-Mail:<?php echo $row['email'];?><br>
        Gender:<?php echo $row['fname'];?><br>
        User Name:<?php echo $row['uname'];?><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code echo $row[' '] is not displaying the record from database.

Comment: If you echo $uname does it display the expected restults?

Comment: Try var_dump($row) and see what is output.  This will tell you if you are getting a result in your array.  If you are getting results, you'll see how the data is returned and know how to access it.

Comment: also putting @ before mysql_query means if there was any error with your query, you wouldnt see it, remove the @, if only for a while to see if you see any errors

Comment: try to run this query manually in your MySQL...then see what result it  will retrieve..Thx

Comment: If you're just learning, you should also abandon the php mysql library for its more secure mysqli and PDO alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
    include("auth_user.inc.php"); // authrization page
    $uname = $_SESSION['user']; // logged user name
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root"," ") or die('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("userrecord",$connection) or die('Could select database: '.mysql_error());
    $sql = "select * from table_user where uname ='$uname'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Mysql error: '.mysql_error.' - '.mysql_errno());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> and its table name is **tbl_user**

And your SQL was `table_user`?

Anyway, I didn't see others mistake with your code, just that. If it was a typo, try to debug your connection, and give us the error message...

Answer (score 0):

no need for this @ symbol:

```
$result=@mysql_query($sql,$connection);
```

Correction:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
```

Comment: that's for error halt, he could use: ``$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die('Mysql Connection');``

Comment: This doesn't help one bit, because all you've done is remove error suppression.

Comment: if the reason their code wont work is because of a sql error, then removing the error suppression will help.